# How to get FragmentManager for PreferenceActivity on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Should i inherit from another activity class? I need to use dialog fragments on `PreferenceActivity` so the Activity should be `FragmentActivity` inheritor. I can use support library but i can't understand - from one hand i should inherit from `PreferenceActivity`, from another - from `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use dialog fragments on PreferenceActivity so the Activity should be FragmentActivity inheritor.

That's not possible, short of possibly cloning the entire Android 2.x implementation of `PreferenceActivity` into your own class that extends `FragmentActivity`.

Normally, dialogs associated with preferences are handled by creating custom `DialogPreference` classes, not via a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: okay, then can i have FragmentManager instance somehow? in order to pass to DialogFragment

Comment: @4ntoine: "then can i have FragmentManager instance somehow?" -- only if you set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 11 or higher, in which case you can use `getFragmentManager()`. If you want to use the Android Support package's backport of fragments, you either need to rewrite `PreferenceActivity` to inherit from `FragmentActivity` or not use fragments within the `PreferenceActivity`. As I wrote, normally, dialogs associated with preferences are handled by creating custom `DialogPreference` classes, not via a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: the idea was to use existing DialogFragments. It's so strange that needed class is absent in support library, i expected to have smth like `PreferenceFragmentActivity`